# Searching and Form submissions Duplicating site URL

Tags: site-url

Having an issue with a site duplicating its base URL during a search result or a form submission.

ie: After searching for a term or phrase I receive the following:
http://www.domain.com/http://www.domain.com/search/...

Below is a snipet of code which outputs the search form.

```
    <div id="search_box">
        {exp:search:simple_form channel="pages|languages|staff|video" result_page="search/index" search_in="everywhere" results="20" where="all"}
        <input id="search_box_input" name="keywords" type="text" onClick="if(this.value=='search for articles, news, videos, and more') this.value = ''" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value = 'search for articles, news, videos, and more'" value="search for articles, news, videos, and more" />
        <input type="image" src="{site_url}/img/bt_search.png" id="search_button" name="submit" alt="Submit Search" />
        {/exp:search:simple_form}
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the code for your results loop look like?

Comment: Could you add some more details? Like perhaps your template code?

Comment: I have added the template for the search form above.  If there is something more specific I can supply to better help please let me know. I am not entirely sure what the issue is, but I am not sure it is within any of the template files.  I assume this because the problem occurs not only in the search form, but also within a donation form during submission.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this parameter:

```
result_page="search/index"
```

to this:

```
result_page="{site_url}search/index"
```

You may need to add a slash after `{site_url}` depending on what that var is set as.